# Android: How can I know a confirmed single tap has ended?

Tags: android, touch, listener, gesture

I want to know when a confirmed single tap has ended.

The `onSingleTapUp` in `GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener` occurs before `onSingleTapConfirmed`.

How can I know if a confirmed single tap has finished?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[onSingleTapConfirmed()](http://GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener) *is* your check of confidence that the single tap has finished.  The linked javadoc will help you understand the difference between that an onSingleTapUp():

> Unlike onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent), this will only be called after the
>   detector is confident that the user's first tap is not followed by a
>   second tap leading to a double-tap gesture.

In other words, you can be certain at this point that the next touch down is not going to be starting a double-tap, because it exceeded whatever the delay Android allows between taps to count as a full double-tap.

Comment: Yes, but is there an `ACTION` or something to let us know that the single tap has finished. Like in case of a double tap, we can know whether a double tap has ended or not by using `onDoubleTapEvent`.

Comment: I don't know what you could be referring to.  The SimpleOnGestureListener API is completely self contained.  The callbacks tell you everything you need to know.